# MSTeams Development: navigate between personal tabs

Tags: microsoft-teams

*sdk version:* https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.6.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js

How do you Navigate between 2 personal tabs?

Currently i am running this, but it does not seem to work. In-fact it seems like its doing nothing.

```
microsoftTeams.navigateToTab({
            tabName: 'Calendar',
            entityId: '<guid comes here>',
            url: 'https://<domain-comes-here>/tab-auth'
        });
```

Am i missing some parameters? or am i doing it completely wrong?

***Update***
I managed to get it to work with by Generating a deep link to my tab
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-your-tab

So in my case all I had todo was add the following.

```
microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>");
```

Even tho this works I would still like to know why the `microsoftTeams.navigateToTab`does not work?

Comment: microsoftTeams.navigateToTab method will only work for channel tabs. To use navigatetotab you will need to fetch the tab instances and getTabInstances will only give you the tabs that are added to channel.

Comment: Ah ok, i wanted to navigate to an normal static tab. I assumed that is what the navigatetotab funtion would do.

Comment: You can use deep-link to navigate to static tab

Comment: Yup, that is what i ended up using thanks